# Django __str__ gives object has no attribute error with a foreign key

Tags: django, foreign-keys

So, I'm not sure why this is failing. I have a model Card that has a billing profile.  Then I have defined a **str** function on it. The field it refers to has  a foreign key to another model's email field.

```
class Card(models.Model):
    billing_profile         = models.ForeignKey(BillingProfile)
    stripe_id               = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.billing_profile__email)

class BillingProfile(models.Model):
    user        = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True)
    email       = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Whenever I don't comment out the **str** method, I get `'Card' object has no attribute 'billing_profile__email'`. When I put `return self.billing_profile` instead of `return self.billing_profile__email` it doesn't error out and it gives me the right email. Why is that? Why doesn't billing_profile__email work?

Comment: It should be `self.billing_profile.email`.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that. Why is that the case?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `.` instead of `__` inside class:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "{}".format(self.billing_profile.email)
```

Double underscore syntax for [related fields access](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) is only using in django queryset, but in normal python code you should use `.` to access object's [attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces).